# Codename One - How to set the width for elements in Gridlayout

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

I would like to set the width  in percentage for num1 and num2. Is there any way we can set the percentage width for field like 60 % for num1 and 40% for num2 in the gridlayout.

Code:

```
TextField num1 = new TextField("", "Phone Number", 10, 
TextField.PHONENUMBER);
num1.setUIID("TextField");
TextField num2 = new TextField("", " Extn", 4, TextField.PHONENUMBER);
num2.setUIID("TextField");

content.add(ClearableTextField.wrap(name)).add(GridLayout.encloseIn(2, num1, num2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TableLayout` instead of `GridLayout` and use constraints e.g.:

```
TableLayout tb = new TableLayout(1, 2);
Container t = new Container(tb);
t.add(tb.createConstraint().width(60), num1);
t.add(tb.createConstraint().width(40), num2);
content.add(ClearableTextField.wrap(name)).add(t);
```